# How can I fix an "error invalid python expression" in the drivers editor

Tags: python, animation, objects

[image: Drivers editor]
I created a driver to have a shape key driven from a sound (in the drivers editor) the Prop: object, in this case a pyramid shaped object that has a sound source (pyramid.003). I also tried driven from a Prop:sound, and the sound is a wave. Neither way works. I keep getting the "error invalid python expression". the expression is var and var (just below the "add input value"). both places show just var, I think that is the way it is supposed to be?
So how to fix the "error invalid python expression". Tks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133289/discussion-on-question-by-roberto-collins-lazo-how-can-i-fix-an-error-invalid-p).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you try to animate a mouth, here a very very basic example.

1. add a torus
2. add an armature
3. Tab -> Edit mode
4. Click on the head of the bone
5. tap E X

[image]

6. click on the head of the first bone
7. tap E X
8. click on the upper bone, G X until so:
9. click on the lower bone, G X until so:

[image]

10. TAB -> object mode
11. select the torus, shift select the armature -> CTRL-P -> with automatic weights
12. now you have a VERY basic mouth rig:

[image]

[image]

---

Sound driven animation:

1. do the things i described above
2. install + enable animation nodes (if you don't have already installed it)
3. add a sound file in the video editor
4. use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

*** UPDATE ***

for me this worked:

[image]

might not be the "cleanest" solution, but it works.

OR use this method:

[image]

right click on your custom property -> copy as new driver.

Then paste this in your bones location variable with "paste as new driver" -> then it works. If enter the same thing manually, it won't work. I guess this is a bug.

*** UPDATE 5 ***

The reason was:

You have to choose Mesh -> Pyramid in the driver panel.

Not Object -> Pyramid.

Then it works.

Comment: Hi @Chris I created a new file per your instructions. I can move a bone to animate. What I cannot do is animate using the sound from the sound bone.n https://we.tl/t-mNYW2QdsKW Suggestions please.

Comment: The structure of answers seems to be changing. The answer by Marty Fouts Jan 14 is true for my comment 3 hrs ago. The problem I cannot find any other path. This is a new file following chris's example which works but does now include the sound animation part.  Please cheers

Comment: @MartyFouts I tried using shape keys https://we.tl/t-74IIqUGvQA and it works but have yet to solve using bones https://we.tl/t-gZLYl63XG8. Cheers

Comment: i updated my answer. I just know how to use animation nodes to get a sound driven animation. You can download and check out the blend file i appended.

Comment: I know there is a „kind of“ barrier to learn it. It is a new way of thinking - as geometry nodes too. But I just can say: it‘s worth it. Watch some beginner tutorials. Check the reels from years ago what they did with animation nodes. It is still (!) much more powerful than GN (but I hope GN will be better in the near future). And it is maybe more open than GN will ever be, because you can write your own nodes by using python and so you have the same power as any python developer out there!

Comment: I have all my life been curious and wanting to learn. But. The barrier that I have is time. My time is short due to a life termination illness, could be half a year or so.  I would like to concentrate on finishing this movie. So since the bones issues is not solved yet, I will go for the shape key way. I'm grateful to all you folks. Cheers

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't know that. Wish you all the best!!!!

Comment: I was able to make a simple file that worked using shape keys  https://we.tl/t-we.tl/t-74IIqUGvQA . But now I tried cutting down my regular file a lot lot: https://we.tl/t-nrKOCQGfxg and back to invalid expression. Please take a look.  Cheers

Comment: your first link doesn't work ...

Comment: ...and as i wrote, i never used sounds without animation nodes. I don't know how to add sounds without it. Do you have a link for me how to do that?

Comment: ok, i watched a tutorial. Didn't sound that complicated ;) and i made a tutorial. Maybe it helps you? https://youtu.be/3fRD_y_r-fc

Comment: I watched your tutorial and commented. I don't know if that is the proper place to chat with you.

Comment: you can write me an email - it is in my profile. I think as comment to my video -  it is not the right place. I think i will delete it.

Comment: don't copy the text, it won't work. Use right mouse click on your custom property and choose "copy as new driver". Then on your bones location: right click, paste as new driver, then it works.

Comment: Hi Chris. Here is a link to a file using shape keys I made that works and packed. https://we.tl/t-ot9DuQbmHO and this is the file that does not work https://we.tl/t-awR21z9YL1. Please have a look. I don't understand where you say 'don't copy...' I copy the path, then go to shape keys, add driver, insert path in the RNA slot. I works fine in the first file but not in the second cut down file.  Cheers

Comment: i updated my answer again -> you need to choose Mesh -> pyramid in the drivers panel. Don't choose object -> pyramid.

Comment: I tried mesh as well as object. the first file works with object. The second file does not show an invalid expression, mesh or object, but no animation.

Comment: the file you sent me showed me an invalid expression. If it doesn't show you an invalid expression -that's very weird. did u try to update blender? whats your blender version?

Comment: I'm using Blender 3.0

Comment: i tried on both version 3.0 and 3.1 -> it showed always the wrong python path with this red background.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg3cj.png

Answer (score 3):

I found the driver (`dad-base` object, go to shape keys, uncheck *relative*), but everything seems OK:

[image]

Now, changing `["Viejo Father"]` to what we can see on your screenshot: `["Sound Viejo Father"]` does cause an error, because no such custom property exists on the target `Pyramid.003`:

[image]

Comment: Tks. I think that what I've been doing is trying different way to animate, such as shape keys driven from an object (pyramid.003), mouth bones driven from another posed bone (made just as a source for the sound), etc. And got confused which was which.  The problem I have now is that using any method, with your help, does not animate the mouth.  I have done this with 'selves' and 'brujo', but can't make it work with other characters.

Comment: @RobertoCollinsLazo whenever you try to do something new, first create a *"prototype"* - a simple project, where you test if the functionality you want to use works the way you think it does. Not only it will be easier to test without a ton of other stuff possibly interfering, but it will also be easier to share the problem in the form of a lighter file. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

The *Path* entry in the input variable section is highlighted in red.  It means that what you have entered there is not a valid path.  Replace the "Sound..." entry with a valid RNA path to solve your problem.

Comment: @RobertoCollinsLazo [What is an RNA (or DNA) property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11961557/1149282)

Comment: @RobertoCollinsLazo You are very welcome.

Comment: @RobertoCollinsLazo I have ~ 60 kB/s upload speed, so I can relate!

Comment: Thank you all. I deleted all drivers + a few other things and now it works. Cheers from an Ol' Fart